# programming hangman in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, if-statement

Write an interactive program that plays a game of hangman. Store the word (single word, not multiple words) in an array of characters called word. Create a parallel array called guessed in which there are *’s in place of the letters. If the player guesses correctly, put the letter into the guessed array. Give the player 5 wrong guesses to figure out the word. Assume that the word will be no more than 20 characters.

so my program is compiling and all but the if statement is coming out wrong, it keeps showing me both statements the keep going and the try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//function prototypes
void game(char [], char []);

int main()
{
    char word[20] = {'d', 'u','c','k'};
    char guessed[20];
    game(word,guessed);   
    getch();
    return 0;   
} 
void game(char answer[], char guess[])
{
    int x = 0;
    char letter;

    while (x < 6) 
    {
        scanf("%c",&letter);

        if (letter == answer[x])
        {
            guess[x]= letter;
            printf("keep going\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Try again\n");
        }      

        ++x;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sort out the enter key and indentation. Give the debugger a hug and learn to love it. As a programmer you have just married. Just consummate the marriage and use it!

Answer (score 1):

Make a change in your code..

```
scanf(" %c",&letter);
 //    ↑
 // Space before `%c`
```

Because when you read a value with `scanf()` `'\n'` left unread which you leave behind by pressing `Enter key`. To neglect `'\n'` you have to read a character with " %c"(Space before %c)